# Can't use declared structure in another declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have header that contains class declaration.

**DialogExInput.h**

```
#include "Stdafx.h"

#pragma once
#include "utils.h"

// CDialogExInput dialog

class CDialogExInput : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CDialogExInput)

public:
    CString timeRemainedSecStr;
    CString Caption;
    int TimeoutSec; 
    int MinDataSize;
    int MaxDataSize;
    CString text;
    int timeRemainedSec;
    void AssignParams (DialogOptions* dOp);
    CDialogExInput(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd *pParent = NULL);

    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT uTime);
    virtual ~CDialogExInput();
    void SetOnTop();


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

};
```

Compiler can't find `DialogOptions`, which is declared in `utils.h`. And `DialogExInput.h` includes `utils.h`.

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DialogOptions'
```

**utils.h**

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include "InputDialog.h"
#include  <string> 

using namespace std;


#define CURRENCY_EUR 978
extern HWND AuthMsgHWND;


struct DialogOptions {
    CString Caption ;
    CString DefaultText;
    int MaxTimeoutExpected;
    int MaxChars;
    int MinChars;
    int ModalResult;
    int inputTimeRemained;
} ;


void ErrorExit();
const wchar_t *GetWC(const char *c);
bool GetProductAndVersion(CStringA & strProductName, CStringA & strProductVersion);
void doInputDialog(DialogOptions *pDo, string & answer);
void doYesNoDialog(DialogOptions *pDo, string & answer );
wstring termToWchar (const char* value);
string getTime(string format  = "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S" );


#endif UTILS_H
```

So where is problem? Why `DialogExInput.h` don't see `DialogOptions`

Comment: My crystal ball tells me `InputDialog.h` includes `DialogExInput.h`

Comment: Yes, that is truth. But why this is problem?

Comment: Circular include, add forward declaring `struct DialogOptions;` to `DialogExInput.h`.

Comment: So, only one solution - declare DialogOptions in separate header file?

Comment: Not the only solution, as you only use a pointer to DialogOptions you can forward declare it.

Comment: @vico: It doesn't look like `utils.h` needs to include `InputDialog.h`, unless there's more to the header than you've posted. You should be able to remove that, replacing it whichever headers and/or declarations are actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

A circular include exists

DialogExInput.h

```
#pragma once
#include "utils.h"
```

InputDialog.h

```
#include "DialogExInput.h"
```

utils.h

```
#include "InputDialog.h"
```

So if you include InputDialog.h before any of the others (where it goes wrong) then the files will be read in the following order

Inputdialog.h
DialogExInput.h
utils.h

and DialogExInput can therefore not see the content of utils.h.

If you add the forward declaration of `struct DialogOptions` at the the start of DialogExInput .h

```
#include "Stdafx.h"

#pragma once
#include "utils.h"

struct DialogOptions; // forward declare as you only use a pointer/reference to it.

// CDialogExInput dialog

class CDialogExInput : public CDialogEx
```

Making a separate include file is also an option.

Also you should break the circular include, checking if you really need those includes. If you don't you it will get back and bite you later.